# How to include my avatar in the emails that I send?

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid, email-attachments, avatar

How can I include my avatar in the emails that I send to clients? The following image is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

I have registered my own domain and send emails using SendGrid... I am not sure if there is a standard email header (such as `reply-to` header) for adding the avatar?

Comment: @tripleee: thanks a lot, I think that's what I need... so I need to create a Gravatar for my email address?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. There is no proper standard, and nothing which works everywhere. Your screenshot looks like Gmail so I guess go with what works there.

Comment: Doesn't look like your example uses Gravatar actually; https://en.gravatar.com/site/check/

Comment: @tripleee: thanks, I have marked the question as duplicate of your suggestions... I might just post a new one re Google+ later (if I get stuck)